# SSIS SSQL Task error

Tags: sql-server-2012

I am trying to update a table using a SQL task in SSIS and I'm getting an error: The multi-part identifier "a.SourceSystemKey" could not be bound.

```
Update BMR_STAGE.dbo.STG_AL_VSAccountStatuses
set a.SourceSystemKey = b.SourceSystemKey
,a.SourceSystem = b.SourceSystem
,a.NLCompany = b.NLCompany
,a.AccountStatus = b.AccountStatus
,a.Description = b.Description
,a.InsertAuditKey = b.InsertAuditKey
,a.UpdateAuditKey = b.UpdateAuditKey
,a.ChangeDate = b.ChangeDate
from  BMR_STAGE.dbo.STG_AL_VSAccountStatuses a, BMR_STAGE.dbo.TMP_STG_AL_VSAccountStatuses b
where a.ID =b.ID
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error indicates either that there is no field called a.SourceSystemKey or that the alias a is not recognized in that scope.  Try using the explicit join syntax.

```
Update a 
set  
a.SourceSystemKey = b.SourceSystemKey
,a.SourceSystem = b.SourceSystem
,a.NLCompany = b.NLCompany
,a.AccountStatus = b.AccountStatus
,a.Description = b.Description
,a.InsertAuditKey = b.InsertAuditKey
,a.UpdateAuditKey = b.UpdateAuditKey
,a.ChangeDate = b.ChangeDate
from BMR_STAGE.dbo.STG_AL_VSAccountStatuses a inner join 
BMR_STAGE.dbo.TMP_STG_AL_VSAccountStatuses b on a.ID = b.ID
```